# Find the most expensive operation in terms of disk block transfer in UNIX

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

I was wondering which operation would be more expensive in terms of disk block transfers from the two operations that I'll present below present below(***All this under the assumption that no relevant data exists in the buffer cache***). Is opening a file using the open() syscall more expensive than reading one block using read() syscall?
It seems to me more sense that the open() operation would be more expensive because in this case all the blocks of the file from the disk should be loaded directly into the physical memory (assuming the physical memory is not too small for the file size), while on the other hand if I want to read only one block of the file using read() syscall then I'm going to have to load from the disk into the physical memory only one block.
If anyone can make this matter clear to me, I will be more than happy.

Comment: Real world performance is a lot more complicated than just saying "an `open` is faster|slower than a `read`". It's going to depend on a heap of factors such as architecture, caching, and so on. I'm not sure this question can be answered meaningfully.

Comment: @Tim Randall I didn't  talked about performance in terms of run time as you say. I know that in order to talk about performance you need to go much deeper as you said. I just wanted to know which function has more beyond blocks from the disk.

Comment: You have not acknowledged that one of your premises is completely wrong: "*the open() ..case all the blocks of the file from the disk should be loaded*". No sensible implementation would do that. Open just reads the file metadata. It doesn't need to read any data blocks at all. Do you understand that point and how it makes your whole question a bit invalid?

Comment: @kaylum yes, you right. next time I'll clarfy myself much better. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about what these functions do.

The `open` function does not read in an entire file.  It returns a file descriptor that can be used to read the file.  The `read` function then takes this file descriptor as a parameter in order to read particular blocks of data from the file.

So you can't call `read` unless you've called `open` first.

Comment: So according to what you say the `read` function is more expensive than the `open` function in terms of disk block transfers?

Comment: @DorI Most likely, however the question itself contains an incorrect premise, namely that the functions do similar things and that it's not required to use one before the other.  Also, any such concerns are a micro-optimization.

Comment: @debush I didn't mean that the functions do similar things.
After all, every reading or opening there is a passage over blocks from the disk on which the i-node of each file points. "Behind the scenes" has access to the blocks of the file from the disk (assuming that no relevant data of the file), So I wanted to know in terms of operating system where there is a transition over more blocks.

Comment: @Dori: if there's truly *nothing* cached before hand, the `open` call is likely to require reading mulitple directory blocks, starting from the root of the filesystem and following down the path until it reads the directory containing the file, in order to get the file metadata.  But much of that is likely cached if you've ever read anything else on that disk since it was mounted.

Comment: @dbush: Re “… `read` function is more expensive than the `open` function in terms of disk block transfers?”, “Most likely…”: How do you figure that? The question posits no relevant data is in cache, and `open` starts with a path. It has to read the top directory from the device, scan it for the subdirectory, read that subdirectory, and so on, until it arrives at the file. (Or, if the path is relative, it has to read from the current working directory.) Then it has to read metadata for the file, check permissions, and stash data to be associated with the file descriptor…

Comment: … In contrast, a `read` starts with data prepared for the file descriptor. Sometimes it will have to read more information associated with the inode to learn where the next block of the file is. Often it just reads the next block.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point, although the post as written has a hidden assumption that you can call either `open` or `read`, when in reality `open` must be called first.  So it's a funny comparison.